# Azure App Service - Failed to load dwasmod.dll

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a .net 6.0 API to azure app service via the pipeline defined in AzureDevOps. After deploying to the app service, when I look at the application logs in Azure after deployment I am able to see an `error` with source `ZipFS`. The message tells `Failed to load dwasmod.dll`. I am trying to find a resource to understand what `dwasmod.dll` actually is, but was not able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please check if you are using the "dwasmod.dll" in your repo. When we deal with local dll files on Azure devops, we need to submit the those local dll files into the repo.

So, you can check if this "dwasmod.dll" is necessary without using the azure devops.